# GenyMotion + Google Play

Tags: google-play, genymotion

У меня есть эмулятор GenyMotion. Как установить на него Google Play и другие гугловские сервисы? При скачивании любой версии Android, GooglePlay там нет.
Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот подробный туториал по установке Google Play Services на GenyMotion - [Установка Google Play Services в Genymotion](http://java-help.ru/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/).